# Spring security BasicAuthenticationFilter returns 403 instead of 401

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have implemented the JWT authentication and authorization. Everything is working fine, besides the unauthorized scenario

**Unauthorized scenario**: making a http call to a route without providing a authorization token.

**Result**: 403 forbidden instead of unauthorized

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String header = req.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

    if (header == null || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
        return;
    }

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

After the

```
    if (header == null || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
        return;
    }
```

Executes, the response is 403

Here is my full class:

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header = req.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {

        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        if (token != null) {

            // setting the user in the security context
            String user = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC512(SECRET.getBytes()))
                    .build()
                    .verify(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                    .getSubject();

            if(user != null){
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }

            return null;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Remark**:

I had the same problem with **UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter**, and I solved it by overriding the default authenticationFailureHandler:

```
setAuthenticationFailureHandler(new JWTAuthenticationFailureHandler());
```

How can I get the correct 401 response code and body?

Thanks!

Comment: The second solution (res.sendError()) should work but I will try to look for another solution as I will have to do it in many places and it is too manual. Throwing the BadCredentialsException will not work.

Comment: I will take a look tomorrow on authenticationEntryPoint. I think if I will pass it in the constructor, the commence method should be called, can you give me a hint on this? Is it enough to provide a new instance of BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you look at what `BasicAuthenticationFilter` which you are overriding with `JWTAuthorizationFilter` does when authentication fails, it calls `authenticationEntryPoint.commence(request, response, failed)` which sends 401

`BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint`

```
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"" + realmName + "\"");
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
    }
```

But you have behaviour that overridden and returning null. So instead of that try one of the following:

- Throw `BadCredentialsException` where you are returning null
- Do `response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help someone encountering similar behavior in using spring boot 3.1.x
I had a similar issue and fixed it in my securityFilterChain method.
The solution was to add the below line to the filterChain.

```
.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
```

Without HTTP Basic authentication configured, the server won't send a 401 Unauthorized status with a WWW-Authenticate header in response to unauthorized requests; instead, it might simply deny access or redirect to a login page depending on how your security is set up.